# How do I change the default height of the System Browser?

Tags: pharo

I am using an older monitor with the 1280 x 720 resolution. The System Browser is just a tad too big for the screen and I want to change its default height. How could that be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how I found the method:

1. Wrote down `'System Browser'`, selected it and searched the methods including such a literal string.
2. Found (this way) `ToolRegistry >> menuItems`.
3. From there looked for implementors of `openClassBrowser`.
4. Included a `halt` to debug `open`.
5. In `NautilusUI >> open` went into `super open`
6. Some few clicks more until I arrived to `NautilusWindow >> initialExtent`. Voilà!

Comment: Way to teach a man to fish. I was using Pharo7 which uses the newer Calypso browser so I had to retrace your steps rather than going straight for the solution.

Comment: Go ahead and add another answer with your findings for Pharo 7. That could help others.

Comment: I do not think I have much to add to your answer - finding the `initialExtent` of `ClyBrowserMorph` starting from your fourth step is relatively straightforward. After that however, I got annoyed that there would be a gap between the menu bar and the System Browser and started looking for where is it getting moved. The default extent only specifies the window size and not the location so I was curious about that. After a lot of debugger usage, I managed to track it down in the `openInWindow`. Right now I think that the window getting displayed outside the usable area is a bug.

Comment: I've opened [an issue](https://github.com/pharo-project/pharo/issues/2800) with my findings. We'll see how it goes. I feel that this session really improved my grasp on how to do debugging in Pharo.